# Cordova silent print plugin by printer IP

Tags: android, cordova, printing

I'm looking for a **cordova plugin** to print some content by **printer IP** on my local network, for and android app
I found this plugin https://github.com/katzer/cordova-plugin-printer but i can't make a silent print with the printer ip address (i guess it works for iOS only), every time it show me the print dialog, even my epson printer won't appear in printers list
Is there any solution please?
PS: My printer is **Epson TM-m30**

Comment: Is there an answer out there for this question +1